# How to get all value from List of Map in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `List` of `Map`:

```
List(Map(term -> check), Map(term -> base), Map(term -> prof.gaurav),
     Map(term -> phone), Map(term -> scraper), Map(term -> with),
     Map(term -> certificate), Map(term -> six), Map(term -> itself))
```

And I want to get all values and check if a term already exists in above list of `Map`.

This can be done by iterating the `List` and checking the value of each map. But I want something more efficient and one liner.

This question may be naive, but I am not getting how to proceed. I am new to Java.

**Expected Output:**

`List(check, base, prof.gaurav, phone, scraper, with, certificate, six, itself)`

Comment: Why use Maps if each Map only contains a single entry?

Comment: above data is coming from cassandra database, where `term` is the column name. Here, single entry is there in each Map because it refers to each row in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you want to check if any of these terms contain a tag?

```
// To check if any of them contains
boolean anyContains = list.stream().any(m -> m.contains("term"));
// get string which did not have value
list<String> nonUsedTerms = list.stream
                    .filter(m -> !m.contains(term))
                    .map(m -> m.get(term));
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `term` defines the term you like to check for existence, you may do it this way:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
    .anyMatch(value -> value.equals(term));
```

Replace `.anyMatch(...)` with `.collect(Collectors.toList())` and you get your list. But you stated earlier in your question you like to check if a term is present.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step we can transform `List[ Map(term -> check), Map(term -> base) ]`  to a `Map( term -> List[check,base] )` and then we can extract that `List[check,base]` using `Map#getOrDefault` method:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("lorem","ipsum");

HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("lorem","dolor");

HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.put("sit","amet");

HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.put("sit","consectetur");


List<Map<String,String>> list = Arrays.asList(map, map1, map2, map3);

Map<String, List<String>> result = list.stream().
        flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()).
        collect(
                groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())
                )
        ); // {lorem=[ipsum, dolor], sit=[amet, consectetur]}

result.getOrDefault("lorem", Collections.emptyList()); // [ipsum, dolor]
```